# https://pub.dev/packages/spotify_sdk used this package and is not returning to the app after authorizing on Spotify App in flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, spotify

Added these to my code

```
var accessToken = await SpotifySdk.getAccessToken(
                   clientId: dotenv.env['SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID'].toString(),
                   redirectUrl: REDIRECT_URL,
                   scope: [
                     ''
                   ].join(" "),
                 );
```

I tried to redirect it directly to Spotify and after that expected behavior should be it should come back to the app but it starts playing music